# Need to extract the key value from json multidimensional array

Tags: json, jmeter

```
{
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "id":313193812,
   "result":[
      [7, "89 NISA SCHOOL - 2 School"],
      [12, "1014 NISA Foundation - Andheri School"],
      [13, "1015 NISA Foundation - Bandra School"],
      [14, "1016 NISA Foundation - Juhu School"],
      [15, "1017 Pharo Foundation - Dahisar School"],
      [19, "1013 Nisa School - 143 School"],
      [20, "1011 Nisa School - 456 School"],
      [21, "1012 Nisa School - 789 School"]
   ]
}
```

instead of using index value like show in the below,i need to extract the key value 89,with where condition as school name(school name to be input from excel)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "id":313193812,
   "result":[
      [7, "89 NISA SCHOOL - 2 School"],
      [12, "1014 NISA Foundation - Andheri School"],
      [13, "1015 NISA Foundation - Bandra School"],
      [14, "1016 NISA Foundation - Juhu School"],
      [15, "1017 Pharo Foundation - Dahisar School"],
      [19, "1013 Nisa School - 143 School"],
      [20, "1011 Nisa School - 456 School"],
      [21, "1012 Nisa School - 789 School"]
   ]
}

if(result[0][1] === "89 NISA SCHOOL - 2 School"){
 console.log(89);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`89` is not the "key", it's a part of "value", see [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) for more details, therefore you won't be able to extract it using either JSON Extractor or JSON [JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/), you will need to go for the [regular expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) like:

```
"(\d+)\sNISA SCHOOL - 2 School"
```

Demo:

[image]

You can replace `NISA SCHOOL - 2 School` with a JMeter Variable from your CSV file like:

```
"(\d+)\s${school}"
```